# Distrobox can´t export applications - xarg throws error

Tags: xargs

`distrobox-export --app emacs` isn´t working as expected.
it throws the output:

`xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option Error: cannot find any desktop files. Error: trying to export a non-installed application.`

Trying to debugging it by setting only the folder `/usr/share/applications` it works properly.
So probably the bug is in one of the queries to find an `emacs` installation.

```
 xargs -t -I{} grep -le Exec=.*emacs.* -le Name=.*emacs.* {}

 xargs -t -I{} grep -Le Exec=.*/home/deck/.local/bin/distrobox-enter.* {}

 xargs -t -I{} printf %s@ {}
```

**To Reproduce**
Install emacs `(ubuntu:latest)`:
`sudo apt-get install emacs`

and export it:
`distrobox-export --app emacs`

**Expected behavior**
Emacs exported to my local user.

**Logs**
(I've added the `-t` verbose tag to `xargs` to extend the grep command)

[podman_log.log](https://github.com/89luca89/distrobox/files/13635281/podman_log.log)

**Desktop (please complete the following information):**

- Are you using podman, docker or lilipod?: `podman`
- Which version or podman, docker or lilipod? : `podman version 4.5.1`
- Which version of distrobox?: `distrobox: 1.6.0.1`
- Which host distribution?: `SteamOS 3.5`
- How did you install distrobox?: `curl + prefix=.local/`

**Additional context**
Context:
I have previously created a `debian` container and exported another application: `VScode`.
I had deleted the container (instead of removing the application first) - and the distrobox asked me to `--force` the deletion of the `debian` container.
This is the only correlation of cause that happened to this behaviour happen.

- I've deleted any shortcut previously setted `~/.local/share/applications`, searched for any dead symbolic link to any shortcut for `code.desktop`.
- Debuged the `export` program, and it seems that it gets itself lost at some directory.
- Tried to reinstall every application: `distrobox` and `podman` -- no success
- Deleted the `/etc/containers` folder and re-downloaded the registries - no success
- I've also edited the directories for search the applications and have setted manually only to `/usr/share/applications` and it works properly. So my main idea is that during the search it finds an broken shortcut that returns a bad string that breaks `xargs` - probably a bad-link generated by the container that got deleted.
- I've deleted all containers from `podman` and started fresh. So probably is some state on my computer that it is leading to this
- Also tried to search for any files `emacs.desktop` or any regex of `emacs` that could have been created with bad format, haven´t find any.

How can I debug it further to find out where it is generating a bad formated string to `xargs`?

--- Solution ---
*This issue can be closed, however, leave it open because other users may have this issue too*

Debugging it I've foundout (now it is obvious) that I had a game on `~/.local/share/applications` with single quote in the name: `"No Man's Sky"` which scaped the `xargs` and `distrobox-export` threw an error as `No file existed`.
So to fix this, you either rename the shortcut or delete it all together.

[I've opened a issue on distrobox](https://github.com/89luca89/distrobox/issues/1097) and I'll probably work on this to add a proper file name handling so that this error never occurs again.